# How to compare 2 character strings?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a typing game and I need to compare a generated string and input string character by character to and then calculate % accuracy.

But it seems am missing something because the function does no compare well.

Am I doing something wrong ?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int percentage = 0;
        int mistakes = 0;
        string input = TextBox1.Text;

        string letter = TextBox2.Text;
        char[] letters1 = letter.ToCharArray();
        char[] input1 = input.ToCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < input1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (input1[j] != letters1[j])
                mistakes = mistakes +1;   

            else if (input1[j] == letters1[j])
                mistakes = mistakes;
        }

        percentage = 100 - ((mistakes / letters1.Length) * 100);
        Label2.Content = percentage;


    }
```

Comment: mistakes always remains zero somehow. 

lets say textbox 2 = asd asd asd 

And textbox 1 = asd asd fds 

The percentage is always 100. Because mistakes does not increment. I am guessing because the comparison is nor working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing integer arithmetic and losing the fractional portion of the result of your division. When you divide two integers, the result is another integer (and you lose the fractional part).

```
percentage = 100 - ((mistakes / letters1.Length) * 100);
```

Given your code above, and assuming `letters1` is 30 characters long and there are 20 mistakes, then `20 / 30` (or any amount of mistakes from the total characters available, except when *every* character is wrong), will result in:

```
percentage = 100 - ((20 / 30) * 100);

          // 100 - ((0) * 100) == 100
```

Converting one of those values to a `double` should retain the fractional portion of the division:

```
percentage = 100 - ((mistakes / Convert.ToDouble(letters1.Length) * 100);

        // = 100 - ((20 / 30.0) * 100) == 100 - ((0.6666666) * 100) == 33.333333
```

Comment: I have been reading all those comparing arrays. Breaking heads over heels to be able to make this work. And I just had to make it double.

I really appreciate your help. You just maybe saved me a whole lot of time. Hell ... I don't know if I would have realised my mistake if ever ...

Thanks so much =)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        float percentage = 0;
        float mistakes = 0;
        string input = TextBox1.Text;

        string letter = TextBox2.Text;
        char[] letters1 = letter.ToCharArray();
        char[] input1 = input.ToCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < input1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (input1[j] != letters1[j])
            {
                mistakes++; 
            }

        }

        percentage = 100 - ((mistakes / letters1.Length) * 100);
        Label2.Content = percentage.ToString();
    }
```